# Repeat multiple rows on each page of ssrs reports

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have a report where I have two groups first is main group and other is detail group and I want to repeat few rows from main group on every page. I have tried many options like static group advanced settings and RepeatInNewPage Set to true. But it is not repeating as my details increases and it goes on second page in pdf then these rows from parent group are not repeating. Please find below screenshot. Please help.

[image]